# wine, delphi, ubuntu 12.04, root

Tags: 12.04, permissions, wine

I'm using an industrial miniPC to have a connection between our system and the office. We have Laundry Dosing Systems in many laundries in Europe..

We have a software, a Utility.exe, which can communicate with the PLC.

In one place, I have a problem running this utility.exe. I'm using wine-1.4 everywhere, and it is working, but in this place I've got 'OLE error 80040154' message, and the program is not running after.

But when I enter the terminal as root (not sudo wine, su -> pw -> wine Utility.exe) it is working.

What can be the problem?

The utility.exe has been written in Delphi by an other programmer.

Comment: Had it worked ever before on the same installation?

Comment: Yes, about 150 installation works with it.

Comment: So it had never worked on the machine in question? How does the deployment work? Was the problematic machine installed using the same image as the others? Are there no local modifications?

Comment: I installed it step by step. but I doesn't set up nothing in wine. Just apt-get install php5 ...etc .. wine .. etc.. and it works.

Comment: And Yes, it was running, I check every installation before ship it.